# Google Un-index / remove page from search results

Tags: html, google-search

I hope this is the right place to ask my question:

For example I had a webpage:

http://something.com/extra/index.html

Then from /extra/index.html I have created a new page (for example http://extra.com) and completely removed the extra folder from something.com

But now, when I try to search in Google "something extra" it show this link:
http://something.com/extra/index.html as it still exists..

Is there anything I can do to stop google search from showing this result?

Thanks..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: delete the old page or do a 301 redirect to the new one.

Comment: it's not SEO.
Reeno, i don't want a redirect, but lets say that because of "political reasons" I don't want that google shows http://something.com/extra/index.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answers is -> use google webmaster tool.
You can remove url search results from google search.